# Outputting struct to NSLog for debugging?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am just curious, is there a way to print via NSLog the contents of a struct?

```
id <MKAnnotation> mp = [annotationView annotation];
MKCoordinateRegion region = 
MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate], 350, 350);
```

I am trying to output whats in `[mp coordinate]` for debugging.

.

## EDIT_001:

I cracked it, well unless there is another way.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [mp coordinate];
NSLog(@"LAT: %f LON: %f", location.latitude, location.longitude);
```

Comment: When dealing with anything C, `NSLog` is pretty much exactly the same as `printf`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I am aware there's no generic way to log struct value - if you know its components you can just log them explicitly as you do with `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. However in your class you can implement `-description` and/or `-descriptionWithLocale:` method and log class instances:

```
NSLog([mp description]);
//or
NSLog(@"%@", mp);
```

There are also convenience methods for creating NString from some standard structures: `NSStringFromCGAffineTransform`, `NSStringFromCGPoint`, `NSStringFromCGSize` etc